# How to manage threads in a C++ framework?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, frameworks

I'm developing a framework with C++, and it contains three layers:

- Low level functions which do the hard work
- An upper layer which uses the low level functions to accomplish tasks (functions at this level generally uses only one lower level function and explicitly accepts the pointer of the function to know which function to call)
- Top level classes which utilizes these middle layer functions to accomplish complete tasks.

The problem is, I'm introducing concurrency into the framework and need a way to tune this concurrency per function basis. I can design an object to transfer concurrency parameters, but I don't want to pass an object to functions which are not concurrent.

Concurrent functions can be at any level and their concurrency needs to be controlled independently.

Is there a better pattern or method to allow only concurrent functions to access this information?

Comment: If you look at the [C++ standard algorithm functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) many of them have an *execution policy* which is added as an extra initial argument to the function (see e.g. [`std::count` and `std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)). Perhaps you can solve your problem in a similar way? I.e. you keep the old non-parallel functions, and add overloads taking a special argument to handle parallelism?

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at it. Changing the signatures is what I wanted to avoid in the first place, since all framework is built upon function interchangeability. Changing signatures (or adding overrides) will nearly duplicate all functions. I have a namespaces inside the framework and I'm thinking of adding a global threading policy object or map to one of the suitable namespaces.